# Iterate through items inside folders and sub folders in SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-library

I have a SharePoint library with document sets on level 1.

Then inside document sets I have Folders and some documents(word,excel,text) on level 2.

Then again inside folders in level 2 I have some documents and folders and so on. I have to write a PowerShell script to go through all the folders,sub folders and find documents and update some columns.

I have tried and I am able to iterate through all sub folders but I don't know how to get the items(documents) in every level.

> Level 1- Document sets
>
> Level 2- Folders and documents
>
> Level 3- Folders and documents

My requirement is to iterate through all levels update a column of document and then go into folders in that level.

Answer (score 0):

I also have or had the same requirement. Just asked here:

[Get all documents from subsite with Powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158129/get-all-documents-from-subsite-with-powershell)

I ended up with the following Powershellscript:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://sp13/teams/it"

foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
if ($list.BaseType -ne “DocumentLibrary”) {
continue
}

foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
$data = @{
 "list" = $list.Title
 "Item URL" = $item.Url
 "Item Title" = $item.Title
 "Item Created" = $item["Created"]
 "Item Modified" = $item["Modified"]
 "Created By" = $item["Author"]
 "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
 "File Size" = $item.File.Length/1KB
 "File Size (MB)" = $item.File.Length/1MB
}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data
}
}
$web.Dispose();

$site.Dispose()
}

Get-DocInventory "http://sp13/teams/it" | Out-GridView
Get-DocInventory "http://sp13/teams/it" | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "c:\temp\Document_Detail_Report_IT.csv"
```

Maybe it is still relevant for you.